# Maximum number of roots/zeros a polynomial $ax^4+bx+c$ can have?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I need to find the maximum number of roots the polynomial $g(x)=ax^4+bx+c$ defined on interval $[-1,1]$ can have.

Intuitive and geometrical example shows that it can have no more than two.
My method is to find $g'(x)=4ax^3+b=0$, gives $x$ with max/min on one point, hence maximum two roots.

Anyone could prove it better/more rigorous?

Thanks,
Li

Comment: You may want to learn to write Latex if you post here, it's otherwise really difficult to read your questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that $a$, $b$, $c$ are real numbers and $a \ne 0$, $g'(x) = 0$
has exactly one real solution $x_0 = \sqrt[3]{-b/4a} \, $.

According to [Rolle's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolle's_theorem), different roots of $g$
are separated by roots of $g'$, therefore $g$ can have at most two
real roots, and in particular at most two roots in the interval
$[-1, 1] \,$.

If $x_0 \le -1$ or $x_0 \ge 1$ then $g$ is strictly monotone on
$[-1, 1]$ and therefore has at most one root in that interval.
 Because of the [Intermediate value theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem), $g$
has a root in $[-1,1]$ exactly if $g(-1)g(1) \le 0$.

If $-1 < x_0 < 1$ then $g$ is strictly monotone in each of the
intervals $I_1 = [-1, x_0]$ and $I_2 = [x_0, 1]$.
$g$ has a root in $I_1$ if $g(-1)g(x_0) \le 0$, and 
$g$ has a root in $I_2$ if $g(x_0)g(1) \le 0$.

Comment: Thanks Martin, I think this is the right answer I have been looking for.